# Can't inject two entities into one jsp using spring/hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I can't properly inject data from two repositories into one jsp form. In index.jsp I have simply "<% response.sendRedirect("category/list");%>" When I use redirect with /category/list it shows my records from Category table and there where should be also records from User category is blank space.

Thanks for your help

CategoryController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/category")
public class CategoryController {

   @Autowired
    private CategoryService categoryService;

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public String categoriesList(Model theModel){
        List<Category> allCategoriesFromDatabase = categoryService.getAllCategories();
        theModel.addAttribute("allCategoriesList" , allCategoriesFromDatabase);

        return "test-main-page";
    }
}
```

UsersController:

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public class UserController {

        @Autowired
        private UserService userService;

        @GetMapping("/usersList")
        public String getUsersList(Model theModel){
            List<User> allUsersFromDatabase = userService.getAllUsers();
            theModel.addAttribute("allUsersList",allUsersFromDatabase);

            return "test-main-page";
        }

    }

test-main-page.jsp:

<%@ taglib prefix="mvc" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

        <p>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Category name</th>
                        <th>isExpenditure</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody
                    <c:forEach var="category" items="${allCategoriesList}" >
                        <tr>
                            <td>${category.id}</td>
                            <td>${category.categoryName}</td>
                            <td>${category.expenditure}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </p>

        <br><br>

        <p>
            <table>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Login</th>
                    <th>Password</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>JoinDate</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody
                <c:forEach var="users" items="${allUsersList}">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${users.id}</td>
                        <td>${users.login}</td>
                        <td>${users.password}</td>
                        <td>${users.email}</td>
                        <td>${users.userJoinDate}</td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </p>



</body>
</html>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mybudget" />

    <!-- Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 1: Define Database DataSource / connection pool -->
    <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://***useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC" />
    <property name="user" value="***" />
    <property name="password" value="***" />

    <!-- these are connection pool properties for C3P0 -->
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" />
</bean>

    <!-- Step 2: Setup Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mybudget.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 3: Setup Hibernate transaction manager -->
    <bean id="myTransactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 4: Enable configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />

    <mvc:resources location="WEB-INF/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"></mvc:resources>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the request is made for category/list then the categoriesList(Model theModel) method of CategoryController is invoked and it adds ONLY all categories to the model before the controller is returned to mentioned jsp page. When the jsp loads it has ONLY category list data as you are not including users data in the model from  Category Controller's method. Hence the user category is blank. If you want to display both lists then you need to include user category data to the model, inside Category controller.

Comment: thank you for your fast answer, is there any way to inject into model two data's ( from user and category) ? without mixing up controllers? With this solution controllers concept in my app is a bit useless

Comment: Yes, you can include the user list retrieval code to the category list method and add the user list to the model just like how you are doing for category list. Then access these two lists on the jsp page.